Error: Class mysqli not found
Me aparece error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in
C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaz\config.php:9 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaz\index.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\interfaz\config.php on line 9

Este es mi código
<?php 
// Incluir el archivo de configuración para la conexión a la base de datos 
include 'config.php'; 
// Verificar si los datos se enviaron mediante el método POST 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Recibir los datos enviados desde el formulario
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    // Validar los datos (asegúrate de que no estén vacíos)
    if (empty($nombre) || empty($email)) {
        echo "Todos los campos son requeridos.";
    } else {
        // Preparar la sentencia SQL para insertar los datos
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios_info (nombre, email) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Datos guardados con éxito.";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    } 
} 
// Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
$conn->close(); 
?>


Tienes que instalar la extensión mysqli o habilitarla en el archivo php.ini, pues podría estar instalada, pero deshabilitada.

pero si dice que el error es en config... porque pones el codigo de index??

Siga los siguientes pasos:

Vaya a c:\xampp\php
Abra el archivo php.ini
Busque la línea extension=mysqli
Elimine ; en la línea ;extension=mysqli
Luego reinicie xampp

